# White Screen Database Plugin Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Currently I'm getting a white screen with 0 error messages thrown when starting my CodeIgniter Project. I've narrowed the issue down to loading the database driver. Specifically to this line

`$this->conn_id = ($this->pconnect == FALSE) ? $this->db_connect() : $this->db_pconnect();`

in DB_driver.php (part of the CI Code).

Here are my database.php settings (nothing too fancy, just testing it out):

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'CI';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['port'] = 3306;
```

When I remove the database-library from autoload everything works (except for DB Queries, obviously).

Any Idea what might be the issue here?

Comment: white screen means you have a php syntex error somewhere or you might be duplicating a function name somewhere

Comment: Does the DB exists? Are the username password correct?

Comment: Turn `error_reporting()` on at all times when developing (http://www.php.net/function.error_reporting)

Comment: The DB exists and user/pw are correct. 

I was under the impression that I already had the maximum log level, I double checked and I do. Alas I still don't see anything in the logs.

Comment: Also, the processing simply doesn't proceed after the line of code I posted, the original CI code intends on checking whether a valid conn_id was established after autoloading, but it doesn't even get there. Processing just stops at that line.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that was more than just a little embarrassing.

In case anyone ever reads this again: It's generally extremely smart to only work with a database after having initialized the module in php.ini. (`extension=php_mysql.dll`).

Works just fine now.